# Как узнать, загрузилась ли страница в компонент webview?

Tags: android, java

Есть компонент webview, загружаю туда страницу:

```
vw.loadUrl("strURL")
```

Как узнать, загрузилась ли страница полностью или возникла ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Идём в гугл.

2) Вбиваем

> [webview android oncomplete listener](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=webview%20android%20oncomplete%20listener)

3) Получаем [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149260/3212712):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
    System.out.println("Ух ты как просто!");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Спасибо гуглу за это", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: @kaaa, это всё гугл) Я тут почти не причём)